# XMLHttpRequest is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in .safariextz file

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, userscripts, safari-extension, gm-xmlhttprequest

I am getting following error in error console, facing this issue for many days, please help.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "localhost Url". Origin
>   https://mail.google.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My purpose is to get an image from my local server and show this image in gmail compose.
This code is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but not with Safari Extension.

If I use Ninjakit to run this code, it works fine. But, if I create a `.safariextz` installer, I get this error. It's not even going inside an onload function.

Code is:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({ 
  method: 'GET', 
  url: validURL, // localhost Url 
  headers: { 
    'crossDomain':'true', 
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'cache-control':'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', 
    'pragma':'no-cache', 
  }, 
  onload: function(responseDetails) { 
    var res = responseDetails.responseText; 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Setup your server to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.  On Safari there *might* also be a per-extension setting you must make, on the extensions page, to allow access to localhost and/or `file://` URL's.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7, which allows Cross-origin by default. And what is that per extension setting, can you please elaborate

Comment: Does Tomcat 7 return the CORS headers by default?  As for that extension setting, there may not be one.  I don't use Safari, but Chrome is similar and has such a setting.  In Chrome you can see it at `chrome://extensions/`, next to applicable extensions, in Developer Mode.

Comment: Hi Adams, Now I have added following CORS settings in tomcat;

Comment: The CORS you posted doesn't have `mail.google.com`.  That's the site you were having trouble with in the question.